# What are my options to blend to pencil colors?

Tags: colored-pencils, blending

I am going to participate in a painting competition and I want to blend the light and dark blue to make the sky.

What blending options do I have with colored pencils?

Comment: You might be interested in having a look at the questions listed [there](http://crafts.stackexchange.com/search?q=blend) especially [this question](http://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/12/what-are-good-options-in-colored-pencil-blending-especially-for-a-traveller)

Comment: Are you using student grade pencil colors or artist grade?

Comment: I edited the question to update the verb tense and the use of the word best which can generate opinion based answers.

Comment: I also flagged this as a duplicate of another question that has coloured pencil blending options in its answers. Others might disagree. If those do _not_ answer your question please explain why with an [edit].

Comment: i am using ffuunn pencil colors

Comment: Do you mean pencil handling techniques, using tools, or using solvents/solutions to blend? Please [edit] your post with more info, as this is a bit too unclear.